# Cert-manager does not create secret

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

I suddenly got some worrying issues from cert-manager.
First of all my system used to work. But now I am not able to issue any valid certificates.
The problem seems to that no certificate is stored.

```
$kubectl get certificate
issues1-cert                         False   issues1-cert                         11m
```

Inspecting the certificate gives:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:        2022-10-16T08:26:54Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      False
    Type:                        Ready
    Last Transition Time:        2022-10-16T08:26:54Z
    Message:                     Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:         1
    Reason:                      DoesNotExist
    Status:                      True
    Type:                        Issuing
  Next Private Key Secret Name:  issues1-cert-z9mcp
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                       Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                       -------
  Normal  Issuing    15m   cert-manager-certificates-trigger          Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
  Normal  Generated  15m   cert-manager-certificates-key-manager      Stored new private key in temporary Secret resource "issues1-cert-z9mcp"
  Normal  Requested  15m   cert-manager-certificates-request-manager  Created new CertificateRequest resource "issues1-cert-sdx56"
```

And correctly there is not a secret with the name issue1-cert:

```
$kubectl get secrets | grep issue         
issues1-cert-z9mcp                      Opaque                                1      13m
```

The certificate seems to be created correct:

```
$kubectl describe certificaterequest issues1-cert
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-10-16T08:26:54Z
    Message:               Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
    Reason:                cert-manager.io
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Approved
    Last Transition Time:  2022-10-16T08:26:54Z
    Message:               Waiting on certificate issuance from order default/issues1-cert-sdx56-4245695607: "pending"
    Reason:                Pending
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type    Reason           Age   From                                          Message
  ----    ------           ----  ----                                          -------
  Normal  cert-manager.io  18m   cert-manager-certificaterequests-approver     Certificate request has been approved by cert-manager.io
  Normal  OrderCreated     18m   cert-manager-certificaterequests-issuer-acme  Created Order resource default/issues1-cert-sdx56-4245695607
```

It seems the issue is with the challenge which return 404:

```
Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: wrong status code '404', expected '200'
```

We are using Traefik as ingress.

I am using Digital Ocean, and we did upgrade the cluster in the last week. This might be related.

In a panicking attempt I have upgraded cert-manager to 1.9.1. Without any luck either.

Comment: What version of Kubernetes did you upgrade from and upgrade to?

Comment: If you use `kubectl describe challenge -A` followed by `kubectl describe challenge <challenge-name>`, you will find indicators to why it's not progressing